# How to find object 'corhelp' in r

Tags: r

I'm having trouble locating the packages for corhelp in R. This is what I get.

```
AdjMatHARD=abs(corhelp[restConnectivity,restConnectivity])>0.65+0.0
# Error: object 'corhelp' not found
```

Comment: Where did you see a reference to this function?

Comment: Under Yeast Tutorial Horvath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're following the code  from [YEAST 
Gene Co-expression Network Analysis R Tutorial](http://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/GeneralFramework/YeastTutorialHorvath.txt), `corhelp` is a variable defined in the code

```
corhelp=cor(datExpr,use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

just search that page for `corhelp` to find it.

Comment: Thank you,, I did the search in r, but wasn't giving me the answer.